# How can bytes in char array represent integers?

Tags: c, io

So let's say I have char array that I read from binary file (like ext2 formatted filesystem image file).

Now I need to read integer starting at offset byte 1024(<--that's the offset from start of data). Is there any neat way of doing it. The integer could be any number. So I believe can be represented in integer size of 4 byte on my system (x86-64).

I believe I need to use strtol like:

```
/* Convert the provided value to a decimal long */
char *eptr=malloc(4);// 4 bytes becuase sizeof int is 4 bytes
....
int valread=read(fd,eptr,4);//fd is to ext2 formatted image file (from file system)
result = strtol(eptr, &v, 10);
```

The above is `long` so is this the number to represent a integer 32 bit?

Should `eptr` be null terminated?

Is this correct or not?

Comment: You're using `eptr` wrongly with your `strtol` call. You should not allocate memory for `eptr`, instead `strtol` will make `eptr` point to the end of the number in the string `value`.  Since it modifies `eptr` you loose the original pointer returned by `malloc` and can't use it to call `free`, and have a memory leak.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry it was typo please check now

Comment: You're still using it wrong. You have to remember that `strtol` takes a *null-terminated* string, and converts the digits into an integer character by character. With your allocation (why allocate dynamically, why not use an array as in `char eptr[4];`?) you have space for a three-digit string plus the null-terminator. That means you can have values form `0` to `999` in the string.

Comment: As for the conversion, it's simple decimal arithmetic. Take the first character, convert it to a number, and add it to an accumulator. Take the next character, if it's not the null-terminator, then multiply the accumulator by `10`, convert the character to a number, and add it to the accumulator. And so on. As for the conversion of digit characters to numbers, the C specification requires all digits to be consecutively encoded, starting with `'0'`. So you can simply subtract the character `'0'` of any digit character to get the numeric value (try with e.g. `'4' - '0'` and see that it's `4`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am having little difficulty understanding ur last comment. can u add little bit more to `Take the first character, convert it to a number, and add it to an accumulator. Take the next character, if it's not the null-terminator, then multiply the accumulator by 10, convert the character to a number, and add it to the accumulator. And so on` do I only need to multiply accumulator by 10 or should I multiply character by 10. can u give bit of code to understand

Comment: The number you are trying to read (from the beginning of the superblock of an Ext2 filesystem) is a 32-bit unsigned integer in little endian byte order. It is not a string and there is no decimal arithmetic involved.

Comment: `char *eptr=malloc(4)` : generally it's rather pointless to allocate fixed sizes of dynamic memory. You probably rather want: `int e; int valread = read(fd, &e, 4);`

Comment: @IanAbbott `It is not a string and there is no decimal arithmetic involved.` but its stored in char characters array. What does this tell? Does it mean I need to do what @Someprogrammerdude has said or not. I like to know how to have a normal integer data type object containing integer. Can u tell

Comment: consider using `pread()`, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have char array that I read from binary file (like [ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2_) formatted filesystem image file).

Open the file in binary mode

```
const char *file_name = ...;
FILE *infile = fopen(file_name, "rb");  // b is for binary
if (infile == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file <%s>.\n", file_name);
  exit(1);
}
```

> I need to read integer starting at offset byte 1024 ...

```
long offset = 1024; 
if (fseek(infile, offset, SEEK_SET)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to seek to %ld.\n", offset);
  exit(1);
}
```

> So I believe can be represented in integer size of 4 byte on my system

Rather than use `int`, which may differ from 4-bytes, consider `int32_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

```
int32_t data4;
if (fread(&data4, sizeof data4, 1, infile) != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read data.\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Account for [Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

As file data is [little-endian](http://disktype.sourceforge.net/doc/ch03s05.html), convert to native endian.  See [`#include <endian.h>`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html).

```
data4 = le32toh(data4);
```

Clean up when done

```
// Use data4

fclose(infile);
```

---

> believe I need to use `strtol` like

No.  `strtol()` examines a *string* and returns a `long`.  File data is binary and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `strtol` it might be easier to follow along by seeing some code. So here a very simplified `strtol` kind of function:

```
int string_to_int(const char *string)
{
    // The integer value we construct and return
    int value = 0;

    // Loop over all the characters in the string, one by one,
    // until the string null-terminator is reached
    for (unsigned i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        // Get the current character
        char c = string[i];

        // Convert the digit character to its corresponding numeric value
        int c_value = c - '0';

        // Add the characters numeric value to the current value
        value = (value * 10) + c_value;

        // Note the multiplication with 10: That's because decimal numbers are base 10
    }

    // Now the string have been converted to its decimal integer value, return it
    return value;
}
```

If we call it with the string `"123"` and unroll the loop what's happening is this:

```
// First iteration
char c = string[0];  // c = '1'
int c_value = c - '0';  // c_value = 1
value = (value * 10) + c_value;  // value = (0 * 10) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1

// Second iteration
char c = string[0];  // c = '2'
int c_value = c - '0';  // c_value = 2
value = (value * 10) + c_value;  // value = (1 * 10) + 2 = 10 + 2 = 12

// Third iteration
char c = string[0];  // c = '3'
int c_value = c - '0';  // c_value = 3
value = (value * 10) + c_value;  // value = (12 * 10) + 3 = 120 + 3 = 123
```

In the fourth iteration we reach the string null-terminator and the loop ends with `value` being equal to the `int` value `123`.

I hope this makes it a little clearer about how string to number conversions are working.

---

While the above is for strings, if you read the raw binary bits of an existing `int` value, then you should not call `strtol` because the data isn't a string.

Instead you basically interpret the four bytes as a single 32-bit value.

Unfortunately it's not easy to explain how these bits are interpreted without knowing a thing or two about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Endianness is how the bytes are ordered to make up the integer value. Taking the (hexadecimal) number `0x01020304` they can be stored either as `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x03` and `0x04` (this is called big-endian); **Or** as `0x04`, `0x03`, `0x02` and `0x01` (this is called little-endian).

On a little-endian system (your normal PC-like system) say you have an array like this:

```
char bytes[4] = { 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01 };
```

then you could copy it into an `int`:

```
int value;
memcpy(&value, bytes, 4);
```

and that will make the `int` variable `value` equal to `0x01020304`.